# Prove that there is no continuous surjection from $S^n$ to $\mathbb{R}_n$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

Let $S^n = \{(x_1, . . . , x_{n+1}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \mid \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} x_k^2 = 1\}$. Prove that there is no continuous surjection $f : S^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: No, $S^n$ is not a sequence...

Answer (score 5):

Since $S^n$ is compact, and continuous image of a compact set is compact... The image of $S^n$ under a continuous mapping cannot cover $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: How do you know that Sn is compact?

Comment: Closed and bounded set